# Insert Contact into Case - Lookup(Contact) with APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup

I have created a simple form that creates a new record in a Case when submitted.  I can populate the text/String fields ok but the "Contact" field is giving me trouble because it is a Lookup(Contact) field.

I have the Contact's ID that I want to use to populate this field with. (0000a000000XXXX)

This is my current code.

```
public class program_evaluation_con {

public Boolean submitDisabled { get; set; }
public String feedbackName { get; set; }
public PageReference thankyou = Page.thankyou;

Case feedback = new Case();
              
public program_evaluation_con() {
// on load disable submit
submitDisabled = false;
    

}

 public void preSubmitCase() {
    List<Case> feedback = [SELECT Id FROM Case 
        WHERE CaseNumber = :feedbackName];
    // if there are records, this would be true
    submitDisabled = feedback.size() == 1;
 }

public PageReference submitCase() {
    //form submition function
    Contact feedbackContact = new Contact();
    //feedbackContact = 'Victor Mews';
    
    
 feedback.Description = 'test description ok';
 feedback.Subject = 'test subject ok';
 
 insert feedback;
 return thankyou;
}
```

Comment: where does the contactId come from?  Is it from the form?

Comment: Yes,  @cropredy I will bring it across from my VFP form.  I plan to populate the field from the URL parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the VF  controller has a valid contactId, then creating a Case wouuld look like

```
public PageReference submitCase() {
    this.feedback = new Case(
       ContactId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('contactid'),
       Description = '...',
       Subject = '..'
    }
    insert this.feeback;
    return this.thankyou;
}
```

assuming that the URL for the page includes a `contactid=003xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, Im getting an error "Variable does not exist: ApexPages.currentPage"

The field details:
Field Label: Contact  Name 
Field Name: Contact 
Data Type: Lookup(Contact)

Comment: I'm going to make this as correct because it works when I hard code the id.  ContactId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; the error is about the URL Parameters. Thanks @cropredy

Comment: I had a typo which I fixed that explains the Variable doesn't exist error